# What is a dispenser

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is a dispenser in minecraft pocket edition. I was doing something in my red stone book and it said place a dispenser on top of that so I was trying to figure that out but I don't know I asked sir but she didn't say anything!

Comment: What is that redstone book? Is that for computer version?

Answer (score 1):

Dispensers don't exist in Minecraft Pocket Edition for now.

---

I think your redstone book is for computer version (Minecraft PC/Mac version). A lot of things in PC version does not exist in Minecraft PE, so if you are playing PE, don't use that book.